# updating specific numpy matrix columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following list of indices `[2 4 3 4]` which correspond to my target indices. I'm creating a matrix of zeroes with the following line of code `targets = np.zeros((features.shape[0], 5))`. Im wondering if its possible to slice in such a way that I could update the specific indices all at once and set those values to 1 without a for loop, ideally the matrix would look like
`([0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,1])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
targets = np.zeros((4, 5))
ind = [2, 4, 3, 4]
targets[np.arange(0, 4), ind] = 1
```

Here is the result:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```